# Some History object still show "MISSING LABEL" message when use Schema to get label or get label plural

Tags: apex, developer, schema

I try get some objects label or label plural by using Schema method, but for some of History objects I will get follow message in label and label plural:

"__ MISSING LABEL __ PropertyFile - val ShipmentItem not found in section StandardHistoryLabel"

Repro Steps
Open Develop Console
Click "Open Execute Anonymous Window"
Input follow code:

```
Schema.SObjectType res = ((SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.ShipmentItemHistory').newInstance())).getSObjectType();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = res.getDescribe();
System.debug(dsr.getLabelPlural());
System.debug(dsr.getLabel());
```

In log you will see debug value like follow image
[image]

After test I found follow objects also has this problem:

- ShipmentItemHistory
- WebCartHistory
- BranchUnitBusinessMemberHistory (Financial Service    Cloud)

I also found old fixed Know Issue like this, please see link:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008wOUQAY

So I wonder is this a Salesforce regression issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the error message for any label not found to be set in the internal codebase. I doubt it's a regression, but rather something that was never initially created when the objects were introduced.

You can see many previous permutations of this error for different objects & scenarios that were fixed previously

- [CaseAggregatedStepHeaderTitle](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMPjQAO&_ga=2.166773566.1609623705.1655299578-1162953017.1655299578)
- [HasUnlimitedErbScoringRequests](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001qYaNQAU&_ga=2.166773566.1609623705.1655299578-1162953017.1655299578)
- [InteractionObjectStateDefinition](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000028vFJQAY&_ga=2.166773566.1609623705.1655299578-1162953017.1655299578)
- [WorkOrder](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001qHFiQAM&_ga=2.166773566.1609623705.1655299578-1162953017.1655299578)

Your best bet would be to create a support case to get the relevant teams notified to add the label for their object history